# Make sure every occurence of char is followed by another char in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash

I have a pretty  simple code that looks like this:

```
txt="hard==2.3.3 soft==2.1.1 weak rep=2.1"

if [[ $txt =~ ([^\=]\=\=[^\=])* ]]; then
    echo "Good"
else
    echo "Bad"

# Output is "Bad"
```

I want the `if` statement to be true only when there is `==`, so if there is a solo `=` or if there's a `===` it's false. So basically, if there is a `=`, there has to be a second one right after. If there is no `=` (like with `weak`) then it's fine.

The problem with my code is that as soon as there's at least one `==` in txt, the `if` will be true. Is there a way to make sure that there's a second `=` for every occurrence? Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need `([^=]|^)=($|[^=])|===` regex and if it matches, return "Bad".

Comment: You're missing some quotes: `txt=hard==2.3.3 soft==2.1.1 weak rep=2.1` will give you `weak: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to *reject* cases of single-equals or three-or-more-equals. Your current if-statement *accepts* double-equals.

So you should do this:

```
txt='hard==2.3.3 soft==2.1.1 weak rep=2.1';

function eq {
    txt="$1";
    if [[ ! $txt =~ (^|[^=])=([^=]|$)|={3,} ]]; then
        echo "Good"
    else
        echo "Bad"
    fi;
} ## end eq()
```

---

Extensive testing:

```
## test one case at a time
eq 'x    '; ## Good
eq '=    '; ## Bad
eq 'x=   '; ## Bad
eq '=x   '; ## Bad
eq 'x=x  '; ## Bad
eq '==   '; ## Good
eq 'x==  '; ## Good
eq '==x  '; ## Good
eq 'x==x '; ## Good
eq '===  '; ## Bad
eq 'x=== '; ## Bad
eq '===x '; ## Bad
eq 'x===x'; ## Bad

## test all pairwise combinations
eq 'x    =    '; ## Bad
eq 'x    x=   '; ## Bad
eq 'x    =x   '; ## Bad
eq 'x    x=x  '; ## Bad
eq 'x    ==   '; ## Good
eq 'x    x==  '; ## Good
eq 'x    ==x  '; ## Good
eq 'x    x==x '; ## Good
eq 'x    ===  '; ## Bad
eq 'x    x=== '; ## Bad
eq 'x    ===x '; ## Bad
eq 'x    x===x'; ## Bad
eq '=    x=   '; ## Bad
eq '=    =x   '; ## Bad
eq '=    x=x  '; ## Bad
eq '=    ==   '; ## Bad
eq '=    x==  '; ## Bad
eq '=    ==x  '; ## Bad
eq '=    x==x '; ## Bad
eq '=    ===  '; ## Bad
eq '=    x=== '; ## Bad
eq '=    ===x '; ## Bad
eq '=    x===x'; ## Bad
eq 'x=   =x   '; ## Bad
eq 'x=   x=x  '; ## Bad
eq 'x=   ==   '; ## Bad
eq 'x=   x==  '; ## Bad
eq 'x=   ==x  '; ## Bad
eq 'x=   x==x '; ## Bad
eq 'x=   ===  '; ## Bad
eq 'x=   x=== '; ## Bad
eq 'x=   ===x '; ## Bad
eq 'x=   x===x'; ## Bad
eq '=x   x=x  '; ## Bad
eq '=x   ==   '; ## Bad
eq '=x   x==  '; ## Bad
eq '=x   ==x  '; ## Bad
eq '=x   x==x '; ## Bad
eq '=x   ===  '; ## Bad
eq '=x   x=== '; ## Bad
eq '=x   ===x '; ## Bad
eq '=x   x===x'; ## Bad
eq 'x=x  ==   '; ## Bad
eq 'x=x  x==  '; ## Bad
eq 'x=x  ==x  '; ## Bad
eq 'x=x  x==x '; ## Bad
eq 'x=x  ===  '; ## Bad
eq 'x=x  x=== '; ## Bad
eq 'x=x  ===x '; ## Bad
eq 'x=x  x===x'; ## Bad
eq '==   x==  '; ## Good
eq '==   ==x  '; ## Good
eq '==   x==x '; ## Good
eq '==   ===  '; ## Bad
eq '==   x=== '; ## Bad
eq '==   ===x '; ## Bad
eq '==   x===x'; ## Bad
eq 'x==  ==x  '; ## Good
eq 'x==  x==x '; ## Good
eq 'x==  ===  '; ## Bad
eq 'x==  x=== '; ## Bad
eq 'x==  ===x '; ## Bad
eq 'x==  x===x'; ## Bad
eq '==x  x==x '; ## Good
eq '==x  ===  '; ## Bad
eq '==x  x=== '; ## Bad
eq '==x  ===x '; ## Bad
eq '==x  x===x'; ## Bad
eq 'x==x ===  '; ## Bad
eq 'x==x x=== '; ## Bad
eq 'x==x ===x '; ## Bad
eq 'x==x x===x'; ## Bad
eq '===  x=== '; ## Bad
eq '===  ===x '; ## Bad
eq '===  x===x'; ## Bad
eq 'x=== ===x '; ## Bad
eq 'x=== x===x'; ## Bad
eq '===x x===x'; ## Bad
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! But I don't quite understand what the {3,} at the end is for?

Comment: The `{3,}` is a multiplier *aka* bound in regex syntax. It says "three-or-more of the preceding atom". In this case, the preceding atom is `=`, so the `=` atom together with its bound says "three-or-more equals". According to your requirement, we must reject any input string that contains any instance of "three-or-more equals". Hence, we must test for it (in an alternation group, since there's another regex we must reject, that of single-equals, which is tested in the prior alternation group), and it will then be rejected by the `!` negation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
txt="a===b"
re='(^|[^\=])=([^\=]|$)|==='

for txt in ab a=b a==b a==b a===b a= a== a=== =b ==b ===b
do
    if [[ $txt =~ $re ]]; then
        echo "$txt is Bad"
    else
        echo "$txt is Good"
    fi
done
```

This produces the output:

```
$ bash script.sh
ab is Good
a=b is Bad
a==b is Good
a==b is Good
a===b is Bad
a= is Bad
a== is Good
a=== is Bad
=b is Bad
==b is Good
===b is Bad
```